# How to write & print a PHP cookie in the same request?

Tags: php, cookies

I'm not sure why, but the following doesn't seem to work as expected:

```
<?php
    setcookie('my_cookie', $_GET['v'], time() + (86400 * 7)); 
    echo $_COOKIE['my_cookie'];
?>
```

If you put this in a file on a PHP web server and call it with a query of `yourdomain.com/index.php?v=value`. The value only gets printed to the page on the 2nd request. Why not on the 1st?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [$_COOKIE](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php) array represents only those cookies that came in the request from the client. [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) adds an HTTP header asking the client to send the cookie during *subsequent* requests.

Typically, you shouldn't *want* it to appear like more cookies were in the request than actually were. Rather, you should generally process cookies *early* in the script, maintain state elsewhere, and set or reset cookies *late* in the script.

Comment: I just want to emphasize svidgen's answer, which is correct: `set_cookie` will set the browser cookies when the _response_ is _sent from the server_. `$_COOKIE` *only* contains cookies sent from the _browser_ to the _server_ in the _request_. This *requires* that there be a full round-trip from the server to the client and back to the server *before* something you put in with `set_cookie` will show up in `$_COOKIE`.

Answer (score 1):

`setcookie("my_cookie", "value")` creates a HTTP header, `Set-Cookie: my_cookie=value`, in the  response to the browser. The browser stores this cookie.

The next time the same client calls the server, it will include the cookie in the request as a header, `Cookie: my_cookie=value`, and php makes it available as `$_COOKIE['my_cookie']`.

You can also check this with `print_r($_COOKIE)` or `print_r($_REQUEST)` for the raw headers.