# Drop down list selected value update after onchange script has loaded (PHP, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, php

**Goal:** When onChange script loads new URL, selected value has to change too for displaying new selected value.

**Problem:** Selected value does not update after onChange action but will do so after refresh. It will set the cookie "lng" to correct value as it should.

When user selects new language I set it to user cookie file under "lng". With PHP I get the value but it does not update the selected value.

**Here is my code:**

```
               <select onChange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value" class="form-control">
                    <option <?php if($_COOKIE['lng'] === "EN") { echo "selected='seleceted'"; } ?> value="/">English</a></option>
                    <option <?php if($_COOKIE['lng'] === "FI") { echo "selected='seleceted'"; } ?> value="/fi/">Suomi</option>
                    <option <?php if($_COOKIE['lng'] === "ET") { echo "selected='seleceted'"; } ?> value="/et/">Eesti</option>
                    <option <?php if($_COOKIE['lng'] === "SV") { echo "selected='seleceted'"; } ?> value="/sv/">Svenska</option>
                    <option <?php if($_COOKIE['lng'] === "FR") { echo "selected='seleceted'"; } ?> value="/fr/">Français</option>
                    <option <?php if($_COOKIE['lng'] === "IT") { echo "selected='seleceted'"; } ?> value="/it/">Italiano</option>
                </select>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but doing `selected="selected"` doesn't work on Firefox.

Comment: Tested, it works with Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18033550/185553) - `set_cookie` will set the browser cookies when the response is sent *from* the server. `$_COOKIE` only contains cookies sent *from* the browser to the server in the request. This requires that there be a full round-trip from the server to the client and back to the server before something you put in with `set_cookie` will show up in `$_COOKIE`.

This is why it works on page refresh and not initially.